# Azure VM - TCP listener is not working for custom port

Tags: c#, azure, tcp, azure-virtual-machine, tcplistener

I'm trying to establish a TCP connection between an on-prem client and an Azure VM (Standard B1s Windows Server 2016 Datacenter).

On the VM I'm running a simple TCP server (see code below) that listens the custom port 9000.
The network interface have a public IP I'm trying to use.

```
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9000);
listener.AllowNatTraversal(true);
listener.Start();
TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
Console.WriteLine("Client connected: " + client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
```

I've added an **inbound port rule** on any port 9000 on the portal (source=any, source port=*, destination=any, dest. port=9000, protocol=any, action=allow).

I'm using a simple TCP client on the on-prem side.
TCP client connects successfully to **port 80**. However, it is not success to connect to **port 9000**.

I used "Packet Capture" to see if client request is coming to VM. Yes it is.

```
1   0.000000    XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  10.1.1.4    TCP 66  29678 → 9000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1400 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
2   2.998954    XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  10.1.1.4    TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 29678 → 9000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1400 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
3   9.000180    XX.XXX.XXX.XXX  10.1.1.4    TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 29678 → 9000 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1400 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
```

I used "netstat" command in VM to check if my TCP listener is working. Yes it is.

```
 Proto  Local Address   Foreign Address  State
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80      VMmurat2:0       LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:135     VMmurat2:0       LISTENING
 TCP    0.0.0.0:9000    VMmurat2:0       LISTENING
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you open the firewall(Os level)port inside the vm?

Comment: You're correct. I opened the port (TCP 9000) on the OS level (Windows Firewall with Advanced Security - Inbound Rules). It worked. Thx.

Comment: And one note:  I don't know why, "Allow an App..." didn't work. I needed to use Advanced firewall settings and add rule for the TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

@Murat Thanks for confirming that your issue got fixed. converting my comment as an answer

To access an appllication which is running inside azure vm, we need to allow the port in vm network security group as well as in windows firewall(os level).

To allow a port in windows firewall login to vm>>go to Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall and then go to inbound rules and click on add new rule and select option Port and select protocol type(tcp or UDP) and enter the port number and fill the remaining details and add the rule.